# SQL count different jobs in each departmen

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

I cant figure out a way to show the amount of different jobs that are in each department. The output I get counts all the job_ids even the same ones but I only want it to show the number of different jobs for that city's department.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENT_ID, substr(DEPARTMENT_NAME, 0, 15), 
substr(NVL(CITY, 'Not Assigned Yet'), 0, 20) "City", 
COUNT(JOB_ID) "# of Jobs"
from EMPLOYEES
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENTS
USING(DEPARTMENT_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATIONS
USING(LOCATION_ID)
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME, CITY
```

All help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT JOB_ID)`, which counts how many *different* values there are:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, substr(DEPARTMENT_NAME, 0, 15), 
substr(NVL(CITY, 'Not Assigned Yet'), 0, 20) "City", 
COUNT(DISTINCT JOB_ID) "# of Jobs"
FROM EMPLOYEES
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENTS
USING(DEPARTMENT_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN LOCATIONS
USING(LOCATION_ID)
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME, CITY
```

And you don't need `SELECT DISTINCT` - just `SELECT`.

Comment: I just didn't know you could use distinct that way. Thanks.